# Passing sequential models to Keras Distiller model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am having an issue I don't understand how to debug. I am trying to do distillation on a bigger model and I followed the examples from tensorflow: https://keras.io/examples/vision/knowledge_distillation/

My code is as follows:

```
    def create_teacher_model(img_size, model_name):
    """
    Create, compile, and train the CNN model with TFData and multi-GPU support.
    """
    feature_extractor_efficientnet_v2 = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/efficientnet_v2_imagenet21k_s/feature_vector/2"

    feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_efficientnet_v2, input_shape=(384, 384,3), trainable=False)

    input_shape = [img_size, img_size, 3]

    # Define the CNN model
    model = keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
        hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_efficientnet_v2, trainable=False),
        #feature_extractor_layer,
        Dense(1)#, activation='sigmoid')
    ],name=model_name)
  
    return model

# Example usage
img_size = 384  # or any other size you want to experiment with

teacher_model = create_teacher_model(img_size,"teacher_model")

## Student model
def build_student_model(image_height, image_width, num_channels, num_classes, model_name='student'):
  # Model input
  input_shape = [image_height, image_width, num_channels]

  model = keras.Sequential(
      [
          tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
          Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding="same",
                 kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=1212)),
          tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
          MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding="same"),
          Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding="same",
                 kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=1212)),
          tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
          MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same"),
          Flatten(),
          Dense(1)#, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=3434))
      ],
      name=model_name)
  return model

student_model = build_student_model(384, 383, 3, 1)

class Distiller(keras.Model):
  def __int__(self, teacher, student):
    super(Distiller, self).__init__()
    self.teacher = teacher
    self.student = student

  def compile(self, optimizer, metrics, student_loss_fn, distillation_loss_fn, Lambda=0.1, temperature=3):
    super(Distiller, self).compile(optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
    self.student_loss_fn = student_loss_fn
    self.distillation_loss_fn = distillation_loss_fn

    self.Lambda = Lambda
    self.temperature = temperature

  def train_step(self, data):
    # Unpack data
    x, y = data

    # Forward pass of teacher (professor)
    teacher_predictions = self.sutdent(x, training=True)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      # Forward pass of student
      student_predictions = self.student(x, training=True)

      # Compute losses
      student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, student_predictions)
      distillation_loss = self.distillation_loss_fn(
          tf.nn.softmax(teacher_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
          tf.nn.softmax(student_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1)
      )
      loss = self.Lambda * student_loss + (1 - self.Lambda) * distillation_loss

    # Compute gradients
    trainable_vars = self.student.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

    # Update weights
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, student_predictions)

    # Return a dict of performance
    results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
    results.update({'student_loss': student_loss, 'distillation_loss': distillation_loss})
    return results

  def test_step(self, data):
    # Unpack the data
    x, y = data

    # Compute predictions
    y_prediction = self.student(x, training=False)

    # Calculate the loss
    student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, y_prediction)

    #Update the metrics
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_prediction)

    # Return a dict of performance
    results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
    results.update({"student_loss": student_loss})
    return results
```

I am building my Distiller with the following code:

```
# Build distiller model
distiller_model = Distiller(teacher_model, student_model)
```

And I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Found unexpected instance while processing input tensors
> for keras functional model. Expecting KerasTensor which is from
> tf.keras.Input() or output from keras layer call(). Got:
> <keras.src.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x793bf3692200>

Could anybody suggest what is wrong with my code? I'm not sure at what other details to look at. The example from tensorflow works fine on the a notebook with T4 gpu and the libraries relating to tensorflow seem to be the same:

> ```
> tensorboard==2.14.1
> tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
> tensorflow==2.14.0
> tensorflow-datasets==4.9.3
> tensorflow-estimator==2.14.0
> tensorflow-gcs-config==2.14.0
> tensorflow-hub==0.15.0
> tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.34.0
> tensorflow-metadata==1.14.0
> tensorflow-model-optimization==0.7.5
> tensorflow-probability==0.22.0
> keras==2.14.0
> ```